# Output of $(3-1) in bash

Tags: bash

I found one thing I can not explain in bash.

Command:

```
$(3-1)
3-1: command not found
```

If I do it step by step, it will show as follows:

```
3-1
3-1: command not found

3-1: command not found
3-1:: command not found
```

Double colons there. Why is the difference?

Comment: Don't forget NFS paths: `server:/path/to/executable`...

Comment: I am only getting `-bash: 3-1: command not found`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "step by step" breakdown is wrong because you assumed that the first "command not found" error message would become the result of the `$()` and therefore be re-parsed as a command. This doesn't happen because `$()` only captures standard output (fd 1) and the "command not found" message is printed to standard error (fd 2).

If you run

```
$(3-1 2>&1)
```

you might get something more like what you're expecting. (I can't reproduce your result exactly because my bash error messages don't look quite like yours.)

Answer (score 2):

what are you going to do with `3-1`? if you want to execute it I doubt you have program `3-1` or `2`. try like this:

```
n=$((3-1))
echo $((3-1))
```

I think explanation is needed here:

if you write in bash new line

```
do_smth
```

it assumes you want to execute a program. The `$(do_smth)` mean: execute a program `do_smth` and catch the output. so, if you write in bash new line

```
$(do_smth)
```

it assumes you want to execute `do_smth`, take an output from command and execute command with name it get. `$(( $do_smth ))` is another. It assumes `$do_smth` is a mathematical expression and affords you to calculate c-like math expression.

Answer (score 2):

`3-1` is not found. The error message you get is sent to standard error, not standard output. So, `$(3-1)` is not running

```
3-1: command not found
```

It is running `3-1` and failing. If you try to run the error message, the first word is taken as the command, the rest are the arguments. The command `3-1:` is not found either, hence the error message with two colons.

Answer (score 0):

you input:

```
foo
```

output:

```
foo: command not found
```

you input :

```
foo bar
```

output:

```
 foo: command not found
```

so bash thinks the space separating commands/parameters. If the command you gave with `:`, you get it in input too:

input:

```
foo:
```

output:

```
foo:: command not found
```

replace `foo` with `3-1`, you find the answer.

Comment: My question is more about the $() command substitution. Why $(3-1) does not show double colon?

Comment: @windchime `$(3-1)` is same as `$(foo)`. you don't have `:` in `(..)`, so bash doesn't output "double" `:`. it would be the same output as you input `3-1` then enter.

Comment: That is where I am confused. I though whatever output from foo will be used as literal command in current shell. So, "foo: command not found" will be run as command on current command line. Is that right?

Comment: @windchime yes, but you have a space between `foo:` and `command not found`, bash doesn't think the whole line as one command. try `foo ls`

Answer (score 0):

When you type any command which `bash` cannot find, you get an error message of the form

```
bash: <cmd>: command not found
```

So if you type `3-1`, you get

```
$ 3-1
bash: 3-1: command not found
```

If you type `3-1:`, you get

```
$ 3-1:
bash: 3-1:: command not found
```

Comment: My question is the more about the $() command substitution. Why $(3-1) does not show double colon?

Comment: Because the command `3-1` fails, there is no output for the `$(...)` to capture and subsequently try to execute as a command. `bash: 3-1: command not found` is written to standard error, not standard output.

Answer (score 0):

The shell sees this:

situation 1

```
stdin-      "$(3-1)"   ( run non existent command "3-1" in a subshell ... )
Command-    "3-1"
Arguments- 
error-      3-1
reply-      "3-1" ": command not found"
```

situation 2

```
stdin-      "3-1:" "command" "not" "found"
Command-    "3-1:"            
                 (note that the ":" you typed is seen as part of the command)
Arguments-  "command" "not" "found"
error-      3-1:
reply-      "3-1:" ": command not found"
               (^---^ and this is where the double colon comes from)
```

As you can see, **the shell does not reply with a double colon at all!**

it echoes your "3-1:" and it adds ": reply"